# You are in charge of investing Chipotle's E-Coli source/s, what methods do you use?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

With the amount of geographic diversity that is popping up over time with Chipotle and the outbreak of e-coli, if you were investigating the source of all these issues, and where it could occur again in the future, where would you begin?

While I initially thought it would be very simple to narrow it down, the most recent CDC articles indicate they have suspicions but nothing for sure yet to indicate how to track it down.

I am relatively new to machine learning algorithms, but I would think a feature classification that would take into account the ingredients involved in positive cases, the sources of the ingredients, and possibly even the machinery used or methods of cooking to help classify the inputs that relate to a positive or negative output would be a good start.